# Which regex flavor is used by .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Which regex flavor is used by RewriteRule in the .htaccess file?

It might be: PHP preg, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: PHP uses PCRE, but there are subtles differences between each lang implementation of Perl's regex. Moreover, current Perl regex are not equal to de facto standard PCRE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html

> mod_rewrite uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expression vocabulary.